# Smaller CircuitLab schematics

Tags: feature-request, circuitlab

If it's up to me, the CircuitLab schematics can be somewhat smaller. See this example: [What is the purpose of R2 in this discrete voltage regulator circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/59387/17592).

I tried earlier to make a small circuit on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/59325/17592) but didn't, because it would be way too large.

Can the schematics be scaled to a smaller size when it isn't a large circuit? The main site has this feature [as explained on the CircuitLab forum](https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/feature-requests/topic/c8qncqx8/smaller-exported-images/#comment_4328).

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention the size of the schematic in the first question you linked to, but you beat me too it.  It is well drawn and clear, but *huge*.  It is actually to the point I moved my head back from the monitor to take in the whole circuit at a reasonable level.  Possibly all schematics are scaled to the same width?  Still, there should be some maximum size for all the parts, even if the result doesn't fill the width images are shrunk to on this site.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think you're right on the same width. It might be a tough job for the developers to shrink on parts... but asking can't harm :-)

Comment: There is a decent chance this is on the circuitlab side, but I honestly dont know. I am pretty sure it is just using their image export tool, so you probably need to ask circuitlab to improve this.

Comment: @Kortuk it appears to be that the main site has this feature when you choose "export to png" (see the link I added to my question), so this really is a feature-request for SE.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/automatic-resizing-of-circuitlab-schematics

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CircuitLab dev here. Thanks for submitting the feature-request, Keelan! We're aware of this issue, and you are correct, it is specific to the StackExchange integration. We made all the images one size to fit within the StackExchange layout. But the fixed width does present the "one large resistor" scaling problem that you guys have pointed out here. We'll definitely put this on our list for our next release.

Thanks for the feedback, and keep 'em coming! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot & looking forward to the improvements! :-)

Comment: @weiy Thanks for answering here, if only this meta had rep! We will keep sending requests your way if you want to just tell us when we have sent one in error.

Comment: Any hope to have this feature implemented?

Comment: It's been three year.  Any progress on this?

Answer (score 9):

As a workaround, I make my schematics smaller by adding something irrelevant to make them wider. Either I draw a wide, short, dashed-line rectangle around the whole thing, or I add some small "." text far off to the side.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to fudge the scale that I have found is to add a box around the schematic. It works for those huge resistors.. but there is no way I have found to make the shrunk ones bigger..

[image: schematic]

I kinda like the border too :)

Answer (score 2):

As Kortuk said in the comments, this is probably a feature-request for CircuitLab. I posted it there: https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/feature-requests/topic/c8qncqx8/smaller-exported-images/

---

**Update**: as Signality explains in the above link, this feature is already there in CircuitLab. So this really is a feature-request for StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

When I go in to CircuitLab, I get zoom error notifications (at least from my Chrome browser).  As a new user, I can't tell if this is part of the problem, or the intended solution to the problem, but I have absolutely no idea about what my zoom level is, and no idea how to fix my zoom to be correct when I see that message (and I get big schematics).

Comment: You'll probably get a better response commenting on weiy's answer or starting your own thread here or on the CircuitLab forums.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice little feature with Imgur that it actually stores 3 image sizes

Take the example posted. 
Sure its big (and this is why I use inkscape) but it does the job.

[image: schematic]

However... Imgur permits resizing
To original image is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/020Wv.png  inserting a sizing letter (https://i.stack.imgur.com/020Wvm.png) accesses different sizes.  The downside is you would need to remove the letter to edit the cct.

https://api.imgur.com/models/image

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice to have a way to select the scale ourselves.