# Need an Embedded Logic Simulator

Tags: feature-request

We have the circuit lab tool which is pretty ok for linear circuits, but it would be nice to have a proper logic simulator too.

I have no idea what was involved or how much time it took to get circuit lab ported in, but I'm guessing one of the on-line logic simulator folks, something like [Simulator.IO](https://simulator.io/) or better, would not mind helping port their system here for the visibility.

I realize you can do logic in circuit lab, but the functionality and usability is very limited.

Comment: Nice for what, exactly? How would you see such a simulator being used in the context of StackExchange?

Comment: @DaveTweed we use the simulator in circuit lab all the time to demo designs and illustrate circuit behaviours. It would be helpful to do the same thing for digital questions. For example this question..https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/341935/139766 I had to link off site, which makes it a bad answer since it is not contained in SE.

Comment: The way I see it, circuitlab, on EE.SE, is mainly used to draw schematics, not really to make simulations. And the answer you mentioned isn't a bad answer, since the circuit image is stored on imgur as usual, it will stay there (even if simulator.io goes down). What is important is the documentation. The ability to simulate with the click of a link is just a convenience, and, most often, unnecessary.

Comment: @dim but is not so much better to be able to demonstrate a working model where the user can flip switches, toggle the clock etc, to see how the logic works. Like I linked to in this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/341944/139766 granted it may be used infrequently, but it would be a nice add just the same.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as having a pretty low priority. A PIC or AVR simulator would be more important, judging from the frequency of the questions.

Most important would be to stop circuitlab from making [huge circuits](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/circuitlab-schematic-integration-we-still-get-huge-diagrams-after-3-years-any), but they've apparently abandoned it.